# You can have javascript functions that create other functions. How does this work?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

```
function greaterThan(n) {
return function(m) { return m > n; };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// true
```

I am trying to understand higher order functions. I understand that the above has one function that creates another function inside it. I also understand that `greaterThan10` stores the function:   `return function(m) { return m > n; };`

I don't understand how this results in `true` ? Doesn't passing the 11 override the 10 passed previously? How are both 10 & 11 stored, I don't get this? Thank-you

Comment: `n = 10, m = 11` once you understand that, it should make sense.

Comment: For you reference, this is called as [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Well, specifically, the technique is referred to as [currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);` results in `greaterThan10` having the following value:

```
var greaterThan10 = function (m) { return m > 10; };
```

Therefore, calling this function with `11` as a parameter (as in your example) returns `11 > 10`, which is true.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't passing the 11 override the 10 passed previously?

Nope, since `greaterThan` function is called once with 10. So, **n** is populated with **10**.

After that `greaterThan10` function is called with value **11** which populates **m** (not **n** since `greaterThan10` takes parameter **m**) and **n** is not touched at all as it takes the previous value stored in the reference of `greaterThan`.

Note that `greaterThan` function is not called again, so **n** is not populated again and hence its value remain same.